# Gmail SMTP closes socket on ClientHello with hex 15 03 01 00 02 02 16

Tags: c++, ssl, winapi, smtp, tls1.2

I'm building my own SMTP client (with C++ in WinAPI, but this shouldn't matter). First, I connect to smtp.gmail.com at port 25. It responds

`220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f191sm4468458ite.4 - gsmtp`

I send the `EHLO` message, then I receive

```
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [<I blocked out my IP here>]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Now, I send `STARTTLS`. Response:

```
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Looks good, so at this point I assume I start by sending ClientHello as specified in [RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246). So I send the following hexes (after encoding them to bytes):

```
03 03 5a 9e 49 ff
```

The first two are supposed to be ProtocolVersion, two uint8 bytes with `3` and `3`. Then, the next four bytes are supposed to be the current UTC client epoch time, as a UNIX uint32 in big endian. But before I get to sending the rest of ClientHello, Gmail's SMTP immediately closes the socket with

```
15 03 01 00 02 02 16
```

I'm not sure how to find information on this error in RFC or otherwise. It doesn't seem to be an alert because RFC states alerts should start with a byte of either 1 or 2. What does Gmail's SMTP response mean, and what am I doing wrong in my first 6 bytes?

Comment: Why are you implementing TLS manually at all, instead of using a pre-existing TLS library that handles the protocol for you, such as OpenSSL?

Comment: Just wanted to have some fun with/learn the TLS protocol better.

Comment: TLS is a complex protocol, and encryption is very sensitive, you really shouldn't implement either of them manually, use preexisting and well-proven libraries instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [RFC 5246 Section 6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.1), the structure of message is

```
struct {
    uint8 major;
    uint8 minor;
} ProtocolVersion;

enum {
    change_cipher_spec(20), alert(21), handshake(22),
    application_data(23), (255)
} ContentType;

struct {
    ContentType type;
    ProtocolVersion version;
    uint16 length;
    opaque fragment[TLSPlaintext.length];
} TLSPlaintext;
```

Using this, the received message can be interpreted as

```
15 : type = alert
03 : version.major = 3
01 : version.minor = 1
00
02 : length = 2
02 : fragment[0] = 0x02
16 : fragment[1] = 0x16
```

Now you can use [RFC 5246 Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2) for decoding the fragment part.

```
02 : level = fatal
16 : description = record_overflow
```

Your error seems that you sent `ClientHello` without wrapping it in `TLSPlaintext`.

When I try to interpret `03 03 5a 9e 49 ff` as `TLSPlaintext`, it will be

```
03 : type = ?
03 : version.major = 3
5a : version.minor = 90
9e
49 : length = 0x9e49
ff : fragment[0] = 0xff
```

According to the description of `record_overflow` in [RFC 5246 Section 7.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.2), `length` field cannot be more than 2^14+2048 bytes, but 0x9e49 exceeds this limit. This should be why you got this error.